# why JQuery height() function returns zero?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make my tables scrollable using JQuery. So I have:

```
  $('#tables-section table').each(function(){
    var myTable = $(this);
    var tableLength = myTable.find('tbody tr').length;
    var tableHeight = myTable.height();
    if(myTable.find('.tablescroll').length < 1){
        if(tableHeight > 250) {
            myTable.tableScroll({height:250}); // make scrollable
        }
    }
});
```

the problem is the height() function returns zero and I do not have any Idea why is zero. Because my tables have some data and length function returns the correct value. I also cannot find the css property in the debugger. Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You'll have to show the HTML of the table too. You'll also have to tell how you create that table (is it static in the HTML? Retrieved by AJAX? Built dynamically?)

Comment: Just use CSS. `table {height:250px; overflow-y:scroll}`

Comment: @Wes Foster I want to make just the body scrollable not the whole table that why I am using jquery tablescroll.

Comment: is the function on document.ready or window.load?

Comment: @Juhana I am getting the table data using Ajax and building the table using  simple HTML tags, nothing complicated.

Comment: @Cheshire I tried both and they did not work.

Comment: Ok, then at what point is the code above being run? In the AJAX call's callback function? You really need to show a complete example.

Comment: sounds like your tables are hidden with display:none or are in an element with display:none.  Also as ids are meant to be unique `$('#tables-section table')` will only return the first element it encounters with that id, so `.each` will only run once

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in the comments you're populating the tables from an AJAX call, it makes no sense to do the height check when the page loads, but in the AJAX success callback (or even at a later stage, in case you're doing something else with the data before building the tables).

*The bottom line*: Call that code after your tables are built/populated with data

Comment: The safest would be to invoke a 1ms timeout inside the callback of the request, which will ensure the table has rendered

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I don't think it's necessary as long as the code runs after the table population. I prefer relying on events rather than timing.

Comment: a 1ms timeout is as good as an `after-render` event. I do agree it's a bit... meh... but it works.